# Overload log function

Tags: r, logging, r-s4

I am trying to overload some functions in the context of S4-classes. Here is a sample code:

```
foo <- setClass(
  Class = "foo",
  slots = c("name" = "character", "value" = "numeric")
)

setMethod(f = "exp",
          signature = c(x = "foo"),
          definition = function(x) {
            exp(x@value)
          }
)

setMethod(f = "round",
          signature = c(x = "foo", digits = "foo"),
          definition = function(x, digits) {
            round(x@value, digits@value)
          }
)

setMethod(f = "log",
          signature = c(x = "foo", base = "foo"),
          definition = function(x, base) {
            log(x@value, base@value)
          }
)
```

While the `exp` and `round` functions work just fine, the `log` function does not with the following error:

```
Error in match.call(definition, call, expand.dots, envir) :
unused argument (base = c("foo", ""))
```

This is confusing as the `args` function states that the name of the second (optional) argument is indeed `base`.

Would you know what the issue is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the help page for `log`,

"Note that this means that the S4 generic for log has a signature with only one argument, x, but that base can be passed to methods (but will not be used for method selection). On the other hand, if you only set a method for the Math group generic then base argument of log will be ignored for your class."

So, you can't use "base" in your signature. If you really need dispatch on the `base` argument, you will have to write a second generic:

```
myLog <- function(x,base) log(x,base)
setGeneric(myLog,signature=c("x","base"))
```

On a separate issue, you don't need to write separate definitions for every function like this, you can use *group generics*. In your example, you could write

```
setMethod("Math","foo",function(x)callGeneric(x@value))
```

or possibly

```
setMethod("Math","foo",function(x,...)callGeneric(x@value,...))
```

And this single line of code will make all of

```
 [1] "abs"      "sign"     "sqrt"     "ceiling"  "floor"    "trunc"    "cummax"   "cummin"  
 [9] "cumprod"  "cumsum"   "exp"      "expm1"    "log"      "log10"    "log2"     "log1p"   
[17] "cos"      "cosh"     "sin"      "sinh"     "tan"      "tanh"     "acos"     "acosh"   
[25] "asin"     "asinh"    "atan"     "atanh"    "cospi"    "sinpi"    "tanpi"    "gamma"   
[33] "lgamma"   "digamma"  "trigamma"
```

work as desired (by operating on the `@value` slot of `foo`). You might also want to do something similar for `math2`, which includes `round`.

A third way to achieve what you want is to have your "foo" class *extend* the numeric class:

```
setClass("foo",
  slots = c("name" = "character"),
  contains="numeric"
) -> foo
```

Then everything works as if the objects are actually numeric. If you need to get at the "data part" of an object `x` of class `foo`, then you can use `foo@.Data`.